# Detecting which applications send taps to or view my application

Tags: android, accessibility

Are there ways to detect which packages send taps to my own application or are viewing the screen of my application?

I checked MotionEvent but it does not provide a way to get the package name that sends taps. I am not too sure about detecting applications that are looking at my application's activity etc.